# How does an app know your location when you're using a VPN?

Tags: applications

- GPS turned off
- VPN set to always on and to disconnect if off
- No SIM card. Using WiFi

Comment: Wifi routers and cellular towers have been gathered together with their location. Android location service can make use of this database to calculate your position based on the surrounding known wifi and cellular systems. Some cellular towers even broadcast their location.

Comment: How is the wifi router information gathered? I believe for the cellular it's through 'getNetworkCountryIso'.

Comment: Do you know Google Street view? Those cars have gathered Wifi access points and their locations. And also every Android phone with activated GPS and Wifi can do the same.

Comment: So how to prevent it? Toggle of location? Would that work? But need to connect to the internet... Which would be better, mobile data or wifi? I understand both can be used to determine location right? Which can be used that you could do something to prevent location determining?

Comment: If your phone supports USB OTG use an USB Ethernet adapter and enable flight mode (no wifi or cellular connection). Alternatively there are apps available that claim to fake your GPS position but I don't know if they work.